# URL updating on login using django

Tags: python, django

I have started using django very recently . I am building a service with user login.
Login , I am sending as POST service. There is a template to render , once the user is logged in. 
    But the browser address is not getting updated.

eg : abc.com  the root    my form would be something like 
     "form action="/login" .....>"

Once user press the login button browser URL wil be abc.com/login. After login I want the 
  url to be "abc.com" again .

Pls help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the built-in [Django authentication](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/auth/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users), you can redirect after login or logout by using the built-in functions. You can redirect to a specific page or you can redirect them to the page they were trying to access.

For example, the doc above uses the following example in using the login_required decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(redirect_field_name='redirect_to')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

I highly recommend checking out the above doc. When I first setup Django's authentication, I was impressed that it only took me about 30 minutes to set it up the way I wanted it, and most of that time was reading the above page.

Answer (score 1):

In you use login view, on successful login you should redirect to the page you want user to land on e.g.

```
def login_view(request):
    if not correct_login:
        pass#return response with errors
    else
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/welcome")
```

see [HttpResponseRedirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) or use [redirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut.